# Change grails JSON object after creation

Tags: json, grails

I have a Grails controller action that return a JSON object

```
def someAction(String customerParameter) {
  JsonBuilder json = new JsonBuilder()
  def jsonObject = json {
      someAttribute "someValue"
  } as JSON
  // TODO: if customerParamter is not null add it to json object 
  render (contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', text:json)
}
```

As the above code mentioned, I'd like to modify the json object without rebuilding it with or without the given customerParameter.

Comment: You do not need `JsonBuilder` either. All you need is a map if you are planning to use `grails.converters.JSON` (I assume this is what being used here)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution using the "content" property:

```
   if (customerParameter) {
        json.content << ["custmoerParameter": customerParameter]
    }
```